# Difference Between HttpConnection & HttpsConnection

Tags: java-me, httpconnection

Recently, New API `HttpsConnection` has introduced in Java ME. I want to know what could be the effect If I use `HttpsConnection` rather than old one `HttpConnection` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [HttpsConnection's JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/HttpsConnection.html)

> This interface defines the necessary methods and constants to
>   establish a **secure** network connection. The URI format with scheme
>   https when passed to Connector.open will return a HttpsConnection. RFC
>   2818 defines the scheme.
>
> A secure connection MUST be implemented by one or more of the
>   following specifications:
>
> HTTP over TLS as documented in RFC 2818 and TLS Protocol Version 1.0
>   as specified in RFC 2246. SSL V3 as specified in The SSL Protocol
>   Version 3.0 WTLS as specified in WAP Forum Specifications June 2000
>   (WAP 1.2.1) conformance release - Wireless Transport Layer Security
>   document WAP-199. WAP(TM) TLS Profile and Tunneling Specification as
>   specified in WAP-219-TLS-20010411-a